# Detect presence of scrollbar

Tags: javascript

When the body is empty, the scroll bar is not needed, but if the body is full with content, the scroll bar is necessary. How can I know the scroll bar is there or not without any JavaScript library's such as jQuery?

I tried to change my page dynamically. The problem is I have to adapt my layout with scrollbar.
Thanks!

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
    <html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" >
    <head>
    <meta content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" name="viewport" />
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <title>
    </title>
    <style type="text/css">
    body
    { 
        margin:0px;
        padding:0px;
        border:0px;
    /*    border-color:#FEFEFE;*/
    /*    background-image:url(bg.png);*/
        background-repeat: repeat;
        display:block;
        z-index:-9999;
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        left:0px;
        top:0px;
    }
    div
    {
        background-color:#a0a0a0;
        position:absolute;
        left:0px;
        top:0px;
        width:100%;
        height:100%;
        display:block;
        z-index:-8888;
    }
    </style>
    </head>

    <body id="body">
    <div id="bg">
    <span id="s1">
    test
    </span>
    </div>
    </body>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        (function (d) {
            setInterval(function () {
                w = d.body.clientWidth;
                h = window.innerHeight;
                document.title = w + " : " + h;
            }, 1);
        })(document)
    </script>
    </html>
```

Comment: You don;t need to program scrollbar handling. Make use of max-width or min-width in your element and the  scrollbar will automatically be shown or hidden. This link should help you to implement it. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4134144/css-max-height-and-max-width-at-the-same-time-not-working-in-ie8

Comment: i would show the vertical scrollbar always so that you don't have to compensate and the user doesn't experience flicker. body {overflow-y: scroll;}

Answer (score 0):

You don't need to handle nothing. Just set the css `overflow` attribute to your elements and the scroll bar will be shown when the content size be bigger than the container size:

**CSS**

```
div {
 overflow: auto;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The presence of the scrollbar can only be detected by using JavaScript. However in your case you can use just CSS and let the browser determine if a scrollbar is needed. This can be done by controlling the CSS "overflow" attribute;

```
html, body, .myClass
{
    Overflow:scroll;    #example scroll always on
    Overflow:auto;      #example browser decides if needed
    Overflow:hidden;    #example hide the additional content
}
```